# Listing related records in Bolt CMS

Tags: bolt-cms

I have content types Topics and Pamphlets. Pamphlets are related to topics (e.g. a pamphlet called 'Mass in B minor' could be related to the topic 'music') using 'relations' field-type:

```
pamphlet:
   ...
   relations:
      topics:
         multiple: false
   ...
```

What I want is to list all the Music pamphlets. More exactly, I want to be able to display each topic, with a list of pamphlets related to that topic.

There's a function `record.related()` but it works the other way, that is, I can use it when I display a pamphlet to show that the pamphlet is related to Music; but I can't use it when I display the Music topic to list all the pamphlets that are related to music.

(The documentation says that relations are always bi-directional, but I can't see how.)

Suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

I was simply wrong when I said that the `related records()` function didn't do the job. Here we are (nicked from the out-of-the-box `record.twig template`):

```
{% set relatedrecords = record.related() %}
    {% if relatedrecords is not empty %}
        <p> Examples:</p>
             <ul>
            {% for related in relatedrecords %}
             <li><a href="{{ related.link }}">
            {{ related.title }}</a></li>
            {%  endfor %}
             </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

In general, it seems, if A (a pamphlet) is related to B (a topic), exactly the same method can be used to show either the topic to which a given pamphlet belongs, or the pamphlets belonging to a given topic.

Apologies for getting this wrong, and congrats to the Bolt developers for a neat bit of work.

Answer (score 1):

I now have an inefficient solution. Maybe someone can improve it.

To display all the pamphlets related to a given topic, I created a template `topic.twig`. Within that template, `record.title` contains the name of the topic (eg 'Music') and `record.id` contains the ID of the topic. We need to select pamphlets that are marked as related to a topic with that ID. The following code fetches all the pamphlets into `pamphletlist` then considers each one. Using the valuable `dump()` function, I found that the data structure for a pamphlet includes an array `relation` which includes an array `topics`. The code below works because in my data, one pamphlet can only be related to one topic. Code:

```
{#  to get a list of all pamphlets related to this topic #}
{% setcontent pamphletlist = 'pamphlets'  %}
{% for p in pamphletlist %}
{{ dump(p) }}
    {% for t in p.relation.topics %}
        {% if  record.id  ==  t  %} 
            <p><a href = " {{ p.link }} ">  {{ p.title }}  </a></p>
         {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It would surely be more efficient to use a `where` clause, something like this:

```
{% setcontent pamphletlist = 'pamphlets' where { relation.topics: ... }  %}
```

That would presumably get the election done at the database level, instead of peeking at each record in turn. But my experiments only produced twig syntax errors. Does anyone have a more efficient method?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to filter by content type? I'm trying to do something similar but looking at the dump of a related record my template fields contenttype is always null so not sure how this would work.

Comment: {% set relatedrecords = record.related('pamphlets') %} I think would be the efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Related Content by Tags extension?
This gives you a list of related content by tags:
http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/45073af0-8585-4d5b-b978-fd6405858e0e

Comment: Thanks Jadwigo but that uses part of the taxonomy system. I want to use a controlled list of Topics, so that the user-editor can occasionally add a new topic via the dashboard, which doesn't seem to be possible using the taxonomy system. Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: The tags in the taxonomy system may be modified by the user (a user that is logged in in bolt) this is different to categories - categories are predefined in bolt.
Still the website visitors can not edit tags